# How to create text box in plone site

Tags: python, html, plone

Hi want to add text box and label in plone site
but, that plone site does not display text box 
how can i create text box in plone site

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a static text portlet in that context you need it: folder, page.